# How to Write Coordinates in $C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have in my textbook the following quote

As you can verify, $\frac{(i,1)}{\sqrt2}$, $\frac{(-i,1)}{\sqrt2}$ is an orthonormal basis of $C^2$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

I don't know how to read this, to be a basis we need that the list is four vectors long. But if we take the four vectors then $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ is repeated twice. So these have to be two vectors each in $C^2$ with dimension 2? This notation has never been introduced in the book and I am pretty confused.

Comment: ${\bf C}^2$ is a vector space of dimension two *over the field* $\bf C$, not dimension four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really two vectors in two dimensional complex space,
$$
\left( \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \text{ and }
\left( -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \ .
$$

I think the author has chosen poor notation.

Answer (score 1):

$C^2 $ is vector space over $C$ and it has dimension $2$ so in basis you will have only two elements. If two vectors are not scalar multiple of each other then they are linearly independent. If u will give me what is your linear transformation then only i am able to comment whether these vectors are eigenvectors are not. If matrix of linear transformation of $T$ is diagonalizable then there always exist a basis of $C^ 2$ such that each basis element is an eigenvector. If yor matrix is hermitian then you can guarantee a orthonormal basis such that each of it's element is an eigenvector.

Comment: I am clear about the logic of the transformation, I simply don't understand how to read this notation about the elements of the basis

Comment: yes, author used an ambiguous notation.